# How to avoid appending "null" in Ajax?

Tags: loop, ajax, javascript, json

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
$(".dropdown-item").click( function() {
    var data = { action: 'get_data',
      id: $(this).attr('id')
      };
      var name = $(".m-t-2");


   jQuery.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: data,
        dataType:'JSON',
        method: 'POST',
           success: function(response) {
            name.html('');
            $.each(response, function(key, value){
                name.append('<div class="container"><div class="row flex-cols"><div class="info-block bg-grey m-b-2 p-a-2"><div class="info-block bg-grey m-b-2 p-a-2"><h4 class="h4 underline-sm"> '+ response[key].firstname + ' ' + response[key].lastname + ' '  + '</h4><div class="col-sm-8 text-xs-left"><p class="m-b-1"><b>'+ response[key].job_title + '<br>Tööruum:' + response[key].room + '</b></p><a href="mailto:' + response[key].email + '">' + response[key].email + '</a><p class="m-b-0">' + response[key].phone + ' ' + response[key].cell_phone + '</div><div class=" col-sm-4 text-xs-right m-b-1"><img src="' + response[key].image + '" class="rounded-circle lg" alt=""></div></div></div></div></div>');

                           });
        }  
   });
});
});
```

So, i got my data from database. I now can append it in .each to a div. But how can i implement, that if response[key].somevalue is 0 then dont append the null?

The data is below

```
[{"id":"2","contract_id":"2445","firstname":"name1","lastname1":"lastname","ended_school":"Vara valla Vara
 P\u00f5hikool","ending_year":"2010","ended_proffession":null,"department_id":"43","department":"Pesumaja"
,"phone":null,"cell_phone":null,"image":null,"email":null,"education":null,"address":null,"room":null
,"user_id":"38596","job_title":"pesumaja operaator"},{"id":"50","contract_id":"2444","firstname":"firstname2"
,"lastname":"lastname2","ended_school":null,"ending_year":"1970","ended_proffession":null,"department_id"
:"43","department":"Pesumaja","phone":null,"cell_phone":null,"image":null,"email":"emailadress","education":null,"address":null,"room":null,"user_id":"38595","job_title":"pesumaja operaator"}
]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that by joining strings to build HTML instead fo DOM node construction or a template system, you leave yourself wide open to injection attacks

Comment: I tried actualluy document.getElementByClass and so after, but i got error document is not defined.

Comment: eh you can use jQuery fine, it's when you write `"<p>"+variable"</p>"`instead of `jQuery( '<p>', { text: variable} )`, afterall variable might contain `<script>alert("hacked");</script>`